# rails - DRY respond_to with repeated actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, dry

In one of my rails controller, I must respond to several types of formats, so I use the typical `respond_to` chain:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html   { ... }
  format.mobile { ... }
  format.jpg  { ... }
  format.xml  { ... }
  format.js   { ... }
end
```

Usually that the `{ ... }` part is repeated on several formats. What is the best way to stay DRY on this case? On an scenario in which `html`, `mobile` and `xml` have a "repeated" action, I'd like to do something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format[:html, :mobile, :xml] { ... }
  format.jpg  { ... }
  format.js   { ... }
end
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a side note, I've browsed the respond_to api(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods.html). It says respond_to takes parameters, as well as a block. Maybe the solution is there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried format.any(:html, :mobile, :xml)?

**Example (added 2011/9/14)**

From the [rails doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)

Respond to also allows you to specify a common block for different formats by using any:

```
def index
  @people = Person.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.any(:xml, :json) { render request.format.to_sym => @people }
  end
end
```

In the example above, if the format is xml, it will render:

```
render :xml => @people
```

Or if the format is json:

```
render :json => @people
```

Comment: I had the opportunity to attack this problem again recently. This solution works! So it is now the best answer. Updating (sorry jonnii)

Comment: nice to know my answer was useful! see you around here

Answer (score 5):

Can you give an example of the repetition you're seeing?

You could always do something like this:

```
respond_to do |do|
  format.html { common_stuff }
  format.mobile { common_stuff }
  format.xml { common_stuff }
  ...
end

protected 

def common_stuff
  ...
end
```

I think something like that could be refactored to (I probably got this wrong as I always forget how to use a method as a block:

```
[:html, :mobile, :xml].each { |f| format.send(:f, lambda{ common_stuff }) }
```

Having said that, I think you're better off with the former as it's more explicit.

Comment: I ended up using a common function. It looks simpler than the lambda stuff. Thanks for sharing this.