# How to DRY up Rails 3 controllers by overriding methods like respond_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonp, dry, ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

I'm trying to create a JSONP API for my Rails 3 application. Right now in my controllers, I have a lot of actions which follow this pattern:

```
# This is from my users_controller.rb, as an example

def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with(@users, :callback => params[:callback])
end
```

While this works as is, I would like to DRY it up by not having to repeat the `:callback => params[:callback]` in every action's call to `respond_with`. How can I do this?

**Update:** One thing I've realized that is ugly about my above code is that the `:callback => params[:callback]` option will be passed for any response format, not just JSON. The following code is probably more correct:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with(@users) do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @users, :callback => params[:callback]}
  end
end
```

There are a couple ways I've considered to address this problem, but I can't figure out how to  make them work:

- Override `render` (perhaps in the application controller) so that it accepts a `:jsonp` option that automatically includes the `:callback => params[:callback]` parameter. This way I could change the above code to the following, which is somewhat shorter:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with(@users) do |format|
    format.json { render :jsonp => @users}
  end
end
```

- Create a responder that overrides `to_json` in order to solve my problem. That way I could leave out the block and just call `respond_with(@users, :responder => 'MyResponder')` to solve the issue. Or perhaps I could include this code in an application responder using [plataformatec's responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) so that `respond_with(@users)` by itself would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to samuelkadolph for helping me in the #rubyonrails IRC channel today. He provided a solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/745821), copied below for convenience:

```
def custom_respond_with(*resources, &block)
  options = resources.extract_options!

  if options[:callback]
    old_block = block
    block = lambda do |format|
      old_block.call(format) if block_given?
      format.json { render :json => [] }
    end
  end

  respond_with(*(resources << options), &block)
end
```

I haven't tried this in my application yet, but I can see that it should work. He also confirmed that I could similarly override the `respond_with` method itself simply by changing the name of this method and changing the last line of the definition to `super(*(resources << options), &block)`.

I think this will work for me. However, I'm still interested in knowing how to write a custom responder to  do the job. (It would be a more elegant solution, IMHO.)

**Update:** I tried this in my application and it works with some minor changes. Here is the version I'm using now in the `private` section of my ApplicationController, designed to automatically provide the `:callback => params[:callback]` option to JSON requests:

```
def custom_respond_with(*resources, &block)
  options = resources.extract_options!

  if params[:callback]
    old_block = block
    block = lambda do |format|
      old_block.call(format) if block_given?
      format.json { render :json => resources, :callback => params[:callback] }
    end
  end

  respond_with(*(resources << options), &block)
end
```

Note that I had to change `if options[:callback]` to `if params[:callback]` in order to get it working.

Answer (score 8):

Note that technically, it is incorrect to render JSON with a callback parameter, since you get a JavaScript response (a function call to the JSON-P callback) rather than a JSON result.
So if you have

```
render :json => my_object, :callback => params[:callback]
```

and a request for `/users?callback=func` comes in, Rails would answer

```
func({…})
```

with content type `application/json`, which is incorrect, since the above response is clearly not JSON but JavaScript.

The solution I use is

```
def respond_with_json(item)
  respond_with do |format|
    format.json { render :json => item }
    format.js   { render :json => item, :callback => params[:callback] }
  end
end
```

which responds correctly with or without callback. Applying this to the aforementioned solution, we get:

```
def custom_respond_with(*resources, &block)
  options = resources.extract_options!

  if params[:callback]
    old_block = block
    block = lambda do |format|
      old_block.call(format) if block_given?
      format.js { render :json => resources[0], :callback => params[:callback] }
    end
  end

  respond_with(*(resources << options), &block)
end
```

Also note the correction to `resources[0]`, otherwise you end up wrapping `resources` in an extra array as a result of the splat operator.

Answer (score 3):

THere's a gem that can do this to: [rack-jsonp-middleware](https://github.com/robertodecurnex/rack-jsonp-middleware).

The setup instructions are pretty scant on the site, but I did create a little Rails project that uses it - which you can take a look at the commits and see what I did to get the middleware up and running.

https://github.com/rwilcox/rack_jsonp_example

Comment: This is an awesome gem, requiring hardly any integration. Very clean and elegant solution. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is bit 'low-tech' compared to the reponder solution, but what about just creating a private method in your appliation_controller.rb to handle this.  The params variable will be available to it and you could pass the @users object to it.

```
#application_controller.rb
private
  def jsonp(my_object)
    render :json => my_object, :callback => params[:callback]
  end

#controller
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with(@users) do |format|
    format.json { jsonp(@users)}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194159/rails-dry-respond-to-with-repeated-actions/2194234#2194234). basically you can create a "default" respond_to for your controller so you can just make your all your actions default to responding to json.

was that what you were asking?