# RoR - Two respond_to formats using same block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there something like:

```
respond_to do |format|

  format.html || format.xml do
    #big chunk of code
  end

end
```

I would like to do that for DRY's sake.

Comment: so what format do you want the block to return - html or xml? You can put all the logic outside of the respond_to and then only format it html/xml at the end - does that help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430682/265940 for a better answer using format.any(:html, :xml) {...}

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Respond_to actually allows you to specify your common block for different formats by using any:

```
format.any(:js, :json) { #your_block }
```

Comment: Actually I think this is the only real useful answer. I couldn't get the "Proc" answer running _and_ this one is definitively shorter and cleaner. Tks!

Comment: Also, `format.all` is a synonym for `format.any` if that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a format like this:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :js

  def index
    @people = Person.find(:all)
    respond_with(@people) do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml
        format.js { @people.custom_code_here }
    end
  end
end
```

Which would achieve what you are looking for, if you have a situation that is more complex let me know. See this [article on the respond_with](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering) method for more help.

Comment: Forgive me for answering until now, the thing is that: I want to format.html and format.xml share the same bunch of code but I also have format.js which I don't want it to have access to format.html's or format.xml's code (which in this case it would be the same).

Comment: Use the modified version of the code above. If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

when you

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    #block
  end
  format.xml do
    #block
  end
end
```

or you

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { #block }
  format.xml { #block }
end
```

you are taking advantage of [ruby blocks](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/), which are evaluated as Procs. Therefore you could do

```
respond_to do |format|
  bcoc = Proc.new do
    # your big chunk of code here
  end
  format.html bcoc
  format.xml bcoc
end
```

but perhaps you could move some of that logic into your data structure?

Comment: Ty Alex, I will go with this solution as I can restrict format.js access to format.html/xml's code.

Comment: Ruby blocks aren't Procs.  They can be converted back and forth, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: @MatthewRatzloff My understanding is that block syntax is exactly that: the most common ruby syntax for defining a closure. See [https://gist.github.com/3757938](https://gist.github.com/3757938). What are they then? Happy to be corrected.

Comment: @AlexanderWenzowski There's a lot of misinformation out there.  The ampersand unary operator converts a block to a Proc, which is why it reports itself as a Proc.  Blocks are distinct from Procs, but can be easily converted back and forth.  Procs are actually created from blocks; blocks are simply a lighter-weight construct.  The differences are minor but they have different names for a reason.  :-)  (Also see http://www.loudthinking.org/2009/10/block-vs-lambda-vs-proc.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html)